# Can't seem to input simple character data

Tags: sas

Today is my first day working with SAS.

I wanted to build a minimum working example to illustrate a more complicated problem, but couldn't get the following code to work:

```
DATA temp; 
    INPUT a $ b $ c $;

    DATALINES; 
    home beer pizza
    school tea brocoli
    school juice sandwiches
    park coke macarons;

RUN;
```

I get the following error after the last line of the DATA step:

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

Any idea what the snag is here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the last semicolon to a separate line. 
You'll be able to tell in the editor because the lines will turn yellow.

```
DATA temp; 
    INPUT a $ b $ c $;

    DATALINES; 
    home beer pizza
    school tea brocoli
    school juice sandwiches
    park coke macarons
    ;

RUN;
```

Comment: "The DATALINES statement is the last statement in the DATA step and immediately precedes the first data line. Use a null statement (a single semicolon) to indicate the end of the input data." - SAS DATALINES statement page. This answer shows the null statement, immediately following the last dataline beginning 'park'.